# trying to "setup apache fastcgi"

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

my system is:

```
wx3# uname -a
FreeBSD wx3 9.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE #0: Tue Jan  3 07:46:30 UTC 2012     root@farrell.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
wx3#
```

packages installed:

```
wx3# pkg_info | grep -Ei '^apache|^ap22-mod_fastcgi|^php5-5.3|^spawn-fcgi'
ap22-mod_fastcgi-2.4.6_2 A fast-cgi module for Apache
apache-2.2.21       Version 2.2.x of Apache web server with prefork MPM.
php5-5.3.8          PHP Scripting Language
spawn-fcgi-1.6.3    spawn-fcgi is used to spawn fastcgi applications
wx3#
```

apache's configuration files:

```
wx3# cat mod_fastcgi.conf
LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/apache22/mod_fastcgi.so

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/local/www/apache22/data/php -socket /var/run/spawn_fcgi.sock
</IfModule>
wx3#
```

this is me trying to hit phpinfo.php file from a remote

```
mbp:~ alexus$ curl -I X.X.X.X/php/phpinfo.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 01:28:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8q DAV/2 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Content-Type: text/html

mbp:~ alexus$
```

now, I'm trying to create a virtualhost, so I copying already working fastcgi to get php to work:

```
wx3# cat X.conf 
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName X.X.X
    DocumentRoot /home/X/X/htdocs/
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
        FastCgiExternalServer /home/X/X/htdocs/php -socket /var/run/spawn_fcgi.sock
    </IfModule>
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog /home/X/X/logs/access_log combined
    ErrorLog /home/X/X/logs/error_log
</VirtualHost>
wx3#
```

hitting same phpscript

```
mbp:~ alexus$ curl -I X.X.X/php/phpinfo.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 01:31:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8q DAV/2 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Mar 2012 21:08:11 GMT
ETag: "97c8ef-14-4bb1223c8a4c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php

mbp:~ alexus$
```

What am I missing? Why would it work for default host and won't work it for virtualhost even though I pretty much copy and paste a working configuration from default host and just change a directory?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have bad definition of `<VirtualHost *:*>`, because your server have loaded mod_fastcgi (as you can see in the `Server:` header in answer), but it don't know, that .php have to be done via php5-fastcgi handler.

Have you defined directive [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)? Does your computer know, that it's IP have name X.X.X (use /etc/hosts file, if there is not a DNS record)?

Comment: "VirtualHost" defined just fine, they're both works as expected, the only thing that isn't working is a PHP scripts

Comment: @alexus And what if you change config to remove `IfModule` directive and only remain `AddHandler` and `FastCgiExternalServer`?

Comment: if I remove "IfModule" directive it will perform exactly the same, this directive there just in case if mod_fastcgi isn't present yet apache will start anyway (website will work just in degraded state) and other websites will work fine as well.

Comment: actually the problem is in FastCgiExternalServer (http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer) and not in apache's configuration, basically that directive works across _ALL_ hosts, how would use share that across multiple virtualhosts (especially knowing that it requires path to files w/ php script)?

Comment: @alexus I'm sorry, but is `/home/X/X/htdocs/php` executable and has `apache` rights to exec it?

Comment: Yes, both directories has same access/permissions on directory/files. as I mention before it's all comes down to "FastCgiExternalServer" and mainly because it's shared between all VirtualHosts yet path for directory where PHP script resides are different for each virtualhost it seems that's where hiccups are happening, it's not apache's fault as apache is able to access files without any problem for both virtual hosts (default and virtualhost)

Comment: @alexus And what say Apache to the logs in the first and second case?

Comment: first hit (200) and second 304 (cached)